# Counting lines "The C Programming Language" K&R

Tags: c

My code for counting the number of lines entered seems to work. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;

    while(getchar() != EOF)
    {
        if(getchar() == '\n')
        {
            counter += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Counter: %d", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

But my question is why in K&R's book have they stored the getchar return value in a variable when it is only tested to be true or false in the while loop condition? I see no reason to do that.

K&R's version:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

main() 
{ 

int c, nl; 
nl = 0; 
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
if (c == '\n') ++nl; 

printf("%d\n", nl); 
}
```

Notice the "int c" is storing the return value of getchar.

Comment: What would happen if the first character in your file is a newline?  What if you had two newlines in a row?  Your first call to getchar() munches a char and there is no way for you to know what exactly was munched.

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell right I see, thank you George.

Comment: Think is each call of `getchar()` read a char, read a line in which you many continue `\n` as: try with inputfile `each $'a\n\n\n\nb' > inputfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getchar()` twice ,which will read *two different characters*.  In the "K&R" code they are storing the result of `getchar` in a variable so it can be analyzed within the loop.  It's functionally equivalent to:

```
char c = getchar();
while (c  != EOF) 
{  
  if (c == '\n') 
  {
     ++nl; 
  }
  c = getchar();
} 

printf("%d\n", nl);
```

Comment: @D Stanley, thank you, I have realised my error, I should of noticed it. :(

Answer (score 5):

For example if  first `getchar()` reads newline and condition `'\n !=EOF` becomes true, comes inside loop

```
 while(getchar() != EOF)   

      {
        if(getchar() == '\n') // here reads next character that is not newline
        {
            counter += 1; // missed counting newline , which read by first `getchar()`
        } 
   }
```

As you see above one will not work properly.

Comment: @Gangadhar Thank you for clarifying, I see the error of my ways :(

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is that you are reading a character and checking if it is equal to `EOF`. Then you are reading another character and comparing it with `\n`. This may or may not give you a wrong answer but the approach is incorrect and will fail at times.

In the book they read a character and store it in a variable c and check if it is `EOF`. Then they compare `c` against `\n` which is the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

The reason K&R uses a variable is so that `getchar()` isn't called twice per iteration, each time you call `getchar()`, you change the state of the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Kunal's answer, your version only checks EOF/newline for one out of every two characters, since the second getchar() reads another from the file. K&R's does so for every character.

Comment: Thank you qternion, I should of realised that. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

[getchar()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns the next character from stdin.

When you call it in the if statement you are getting the next character, but when you call it again in your check against "\n" you are getting the char after that one and comparing it, so you are actually reading in two characters each time, which is faulty.